# How can I modify class abilities?

Tags: spells, sorcerer, pcgen

I was reading in this page that you can add spells and abilities to pcgen modifying the .lst files. My first idea was to add an "spell" for my character in order to have a special "ability". Now I think that is better to add it like an air elemental sorcerer ability and not like a sorcerer/wizard spell, in order that it takes no spell slots or consumes spells per day. So, now I'm trying to modify the air elemental sorcerer class to have that ability separately from spells.

An example could be the Elemental Ray, spell given by the air elemental bloodline, wich can be cast 7 times per day, separately from your spells.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do that?

Thank you all for your attention :)

Comment: PCGen can be used for either Pathfinder or DnD 3.5e, are you able to clarify which one you're asking about?

Comment: Are you trying to add a spell-like ability to the creature's sheet? Or a class feature like [Elemental Ray](http://d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/elemental-bloodline) (which is not a spell)?  They are represented differently in PCGen.